# CASE WHEN in Oracle SQL Developer in join statement

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, case-when

I wrote this snippet of code here in Oracle SQL Developer but I don't know how to use a CASE WHEN so that when **k.QUARANTINED = 0**, display 'No', else if k.QUARANTINED = 1 display 'Yes'. This column is always 0 or 1.
    
    `select
    s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
    ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
    ,k.EXPIRATION
    ,k.DISDATE
    ,u.SCR_NO as "Patient No"
    ,k.QUARANTINED
    ,k.PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID
    ,k.SORT_KEY as "Sort Order"
    from KIT k
    left join SHIPMENT s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
    left join USR u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID`;

I tried a couple of times but kept getting errors most likely since I don't know how write the syntax correctly or maybe I have to rewrite this completely differently? I'd like to keep the order of the columns the same. I just would like to see 'Yes' or 'No' for k.Quarantined instead of 0 or 1 returned in the result. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    S.name                     AS "shipment ID",
    K.status_id                AS "status",
    K.expiration,
    K.disdate,
    U.scr_no                   AS "Patient No",
    K.quarantined,
    CASE k.quarantined
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'Missing or Null'
    END                        AS "quarantine status case example 1",
    CASE
        WHEN k.quarantined = 0
            THEN 'No'
        WHEN k.quarantined = 1
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'Missing or Null'
    END                        AS "quarantine status case example 2",
    K.previous_status_id,
    K.sort_key                 AS "sort order",
FROM Kit K
LEFT JOIN Shipment S
    ON K.shipment_id = S.id
LEFT JOIN USR U
    ON K.pat_id = U.pat_id
ORDER BY
    K.sort_key ASC
;
```

Two examples of CASE above. The first example is used when you are evaluating a single column/variable.

The second example is used for testing multiple conditions.

When using the second example of CASE statements, it is important to understand that CASE will return the result for the first condition that evaluates TRUE. When using complex logic, sometimes a developer may (inadvertently) have overlapping logic where multiple conditions can be satisfied. When unexpected results from CASE occur, it is important to go back and reevaluate the statement from the top down.

If you are absolutely sure that K.quarantined cannot be NULL and it can only be 0 or one (research the table DDL for check constraints) then you can remove or comment out the ELSE clause on the CASE statements--but it is generally good practice to always have an ELSE clause for consistency. You can have it simply state "ELSE NULL" if you do not ever expect anything other than what's described in your CASE statement.

Lastly, be sure to make sure to identify whether K.quarantined is numeric or text (check table DDL). If it is actually storing text '0' or '1', then should change your literals accordingly--although I think current versions of Oracle are smart enough to do the implicit conversions for you.